# How to upgrade eclipse rcp based application between releases

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I would like to know if there is a way to upgrade an eclipse e4 rcp application (let's say from 4.2 to 4.3 when I will want to be based on this version) without having to reinstall the whole application?

Actually, I have an eclipse e4 rcp based application that update itself when I have new versions of my features. I have one feature (com.mycompany.myapp) which includes the feature org.eclipse.e4.rcp. I can use a more recent version of org.eclipse.e4.rcp, update the version of my feature com.mycompany.myapp and apply the update on my eclipse e4 rcp based application but after the update my application does not start.

How do you manage this scenario in a simple way for the end user?

Comment: Are you able to provide parts of the [log file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F) of your application when 'it does not start'?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have two components in your setup. The bootstrap and the feature.

Normally the feature component is bundled inside the bootstrap component so they appear as an upgradeable product (Where you just publish the new feature on the updatesite).

In other configurations I have run we had only a small bootstrapper which essentially was useless without an updatesite and on first launch would pick the feature component from the update site.

However, in the end we built a batchscript to update the bootstrapper if necessary using the p2 director. There is some [initial stuff here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html), but you need to do some experimenting..

Comment: Can you give an example how the batch script should look like? I mean which parameters you pass to the p2.director, etc.